# Download an image from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to download an image from a SharePoint site but our SharePoint site is hosted on Windows Azure so it may need authentication.  How can I download the image using C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can download an image by using the WebClient in c#.
This webclient has a "[DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx)" function that accepts a url.
The webclient also has a "Credentials" property where you can assign the needed credentials.